# How this PDF is derived?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I have a random variable $\gamma$, which is product of two normal random variable $h_{st},h_{tr}$ and they are related as $\gamma = \eta\cdot h_{st}\cdot h_{tr}$. The PDF of $\gamma$ is given as

$f_{\gamma}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi\eta\sqrt{\sigma_{st}^2\sigma_{tr}^2}}K_0\left(\frac{|x|}{\eta\sqrt{\sigma_{st}^2\sigma_{tr}^2}}\right)$ -----(1)

From the Simon book "Probability distributions involving Gaussian Random
Variables: a handbook for engineers and scientists.", i know that the PDF of product of two Gaussian random variables is the same eq.(1) except the presence of $\eta$ factor. I am having doubt about how the $\eta$ factor is coming in eq. (1).
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated...

Comment: That is just scaling. In general, if the PDF for a real random variable $X$ id $f(x)$, then the PDF for $\eta X$ where $\eta$ is a real constant is $\frac 1\eta f(x/\eta)$. Just write $P(\eta X\in [a,b])=P(X\in [a/\eta,b/\eta])$, divide by $b-a$, and pass to the limit when $[a,b]$ shrinks to a point.

Comment: ok....understood....